# CFDocument in CFScript (Adobe CF2021)?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016, coldfusion-2021

Is CFDocument supported in CFSscript specifically with Adobe ColdFusion 2021?

I know that this was not possible in previous versions (but is possible with Lucee). However, I can't find any official documentation either way. I'm hoping someone can point me to any relevant documentation on this.

Thanks!

Comment: The Adobe docs on cfscript functionality are spotty, but AFAIK it's been supported since at least CF11 . TryCF.com example https://trycf.com/gist/9da99e6aa19dcee00eaae1c149cf0910/acf11?theme=monokai

Comment: Thanks I wish Adobe docs were more complete but thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use cfdocument in cfscript, in ColdFusion 2021.

To be clear, nearly all tags have been supported as cfscript since CF11, released in 2014. Here's the documentation for that [from the intro section in the CFML Reference](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/script-supported-tags-and-functions.html):

> As general syntax for script support, a ColdFusion tag is invoked like a function call in CFSCRIPT block with tag name is used for the function name. The tag attributes are passed as comma separated name-value pairs to it, like arguments are passed to a function. The child tag (and the body in general) is defined within a curly brackets, just like a function block.

So as an example, this:

```cfml
<cfdocument format="pdf">
test
</cfdocument>
```

could become:

```cfml
<cfscript>
cfdocument(format="pdf"){
writeoutput("test");
};
</cfscript>
```

Note how **you must use a writeoutput within the body of the document** to provide the content of the PDF, even though the cfdocument does not require any corresponding cfoutput. (FWIW, some CFML tags do, like cfsavecontent.) And of course you can use cfdocumentitem, cfdocumentsection, etc. See the docs page about how nested tags are handled in script.

Finally, it's indeed true that Adobe never changed each page of the CFML Reference to indicate a) this change to support all tags as script, nor b) to show using each tag as script.

While it's unfortunate that the CFML Reference is not open source, for us to propose changes, the cfdocs.org site is open source--and I just noticed that their [page on cfdocument](https://cfdocs.org/cfdocument) does not show using it as script, so I will try to offer a PR.